# Pentaho database connection test button not working

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Whenever I try to make a database connection in transaction Pentaho, be it oracle or postgreSQL, although everything is correct in the last part, the test button does not show anything instead of saying the connection is complete. The necessary JDBC files are installed, can you help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Elh.png)

I tried all the JDBC files, and I even prepared the file path for JDBCs, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test button doesn't work because you should download pentaho from https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/products/dataops-software/data-integration-analytics/pentaho-community-edition.html. Don't downloaded it from sourceforge, if you downloaded from here try the 8.3 version.

Tip:If the marketplace doesn't appear install pentaho 8.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved the problem, my mistake was because of the old version pentaho I downloaded from sourceforge, when I downloaded the latest version pentaho pdi from hitachi vartana's own site, the problem was solved
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQOXa.png